# automatically choose video file without using openfiledialog

Tags: c#

I am using AForge code to play video in my program using c# and it works well. here is the code:

```
private void loadButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        FileVideoSource fileSource = new FileVideoSource(openFileDialog1.FileName);
        OpenVideoSource(fileSource);
    }
}
```

This code will play the video when we click the load button and choose what video we want to play. However i want the video automatically choose the selected video after clicking the load button.

i try this code however the video its not even playing.

```
private void loadButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FileVideoSource fileSource = new FileVideoSource("C:\\Users\\videoplay.mp4");
    OpenVideoSource(fileSource);
}
```

Please help me modifying the code. what did i do wrong?

Comment: this "C:\\Users\videoplay.mp4" must be this "C:\\Users\\videoplay.mp4"

Comment: I'm going to assume that the compiler is complaining that `\v` is not a valid escape sequence.. You need to escape the backslash: `"C:\\Users\\videoplay.mp4"`. Or: `... new FileVideoSource(@"C:\Users\videoplay.mp4");`

Comment: @SimonWhitehead sorry without noticed i suddenly deleted one backslash (\v). however, my real code is exactly like you said.

Comment: @BuiAkinori sorry without noticed i suddenly deleted one backslash (\v). however, my real code is exactly like you said.

Comment: in debug mode check what is the difference in the hardcoded string and filediaolg.filename

Answer (score 1):

`\v` is an escape code for a vertical tab.
You need to escape the `\` by writing `\\`.

Better yet, use a verbatim string literal, which doesn't mess with `\`s:

```
@"C:\Users\videoplay.mp4"
```

Comment: Ah yes.. vertical tab. Silly me (RE: my comment).

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the other backslash in your filename: `"C:\\Users\\Videoplay.mp4"`. (You also have an extra closing `}` in your second code snippet.)

The only other reason it wouldn't work is if `"C:\Users\videoplay.mp4"` isn't there, or if the user doesn't have access to that folder (which is probably the case - the proper path would be `"C:\Users\<username>\Documents\videoplay.mp4"` instead).

Comment: it is the same file location that i choose when i use the openfiledialog. and yes, it can play. so i dont think videoplay is not exist. by the way, what machine that you want to see? i dont quite understand.

Comment: Did you step through your code in the debugger to see what's happening? The code you posted should work fine, and you're not giving us any more information to work with here. We can't inspect your machine (computer) to see what the problem is, and the code you posted is fine now after your corrected it. Use the debugger; set a break point on the first line in the `loadButton_Click` method, and step through the code to see what's happening.